# how to calculate wavelength of simple sine function

Tags: trigonometry

I have the following simple sine formula (in degrees) which I am plotting on the screen.  The user is able to change the values of the variables waveAmplitude, angleCoef, and horizontalShift.

```
y = waveAmplitude * Math.sin(x * angleCoef + horizontalShift)
```

I have to also display the wavelength on the screen.  But I can't quite figure out how to calculate the wavelength.

So how exactly can I calculate wavelength for my simple sine function?

Comment: It is $2\pi$ divided by your 'angleCoef'. Try plugging this in for $x$ and see that it gives the same as when plugging in $x=0$. Your 'angleCoef' is usually called *angular frequency*.

Comment: @M.Winter  thank you.  i edited to respond to your suggestion.

Comment: Your plot is clearly indicating that your sine function is expecting radians and not degree. E.g. try 0.01, then $2\pi/0.01\approx 628.3$ which fits the plot.

Comment: @M.Winter  thank you!!!